# How do I enable letterbox for my display

Tags: display, display-resolution, monitor, xrandr

**EDIT:**
It's not Windows OS that provides the setting rather Intel Graphics that does. Apologies for the error. Though still would like to know how to change Intel Graphics settings. (Intel graphics settings on windows: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Zb8pQQ17SQQ/maxresdefault.jpg)

**What I want:**

I have a 21" **16:9** Dell Monitor (as an external monitor for my laptop) that can support resolution upto 1920x1080. I want to use resolution 1680x1050 (aspect ratio **16:10**) with **letterbox** on the sides. (In Windows this is an auto feature and changing stretched vs letterbox is provided in the Display settings.)

**My quest to a letterbox**

To have the letterbox, I have tried various codes from different forums and answers (*their output is in brackets and in italic such as this*):

`$ xrandr --output HDMI1 --transform 1,0,-100,0,1,0,0,0,1` (*moved screen to right*)

`$ xrandr --output HDMI1 --size 1680x1050 --fb 1680x1050` (*did nothing*)

`$ xrandr --output HDMI1 --mode "1680x1050_60.00" --scale 1.6x1` (*stretched display*)

`$ xrandr --output HDMI1 --set "scaling mode" "Full aspect"` (*error*)

**xrandr --prop**

running the following command line to get information on my displays:

```
xrandr --prop
```

> Note: HDMI1 is the external monitor.

output:

```
HDMI1 connected primary 1680x1050+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 480mm x 270mm
    EDID: 
        00ffffffffffff0010acb8d054364530
        101b010380301b78eac7b5a756539c27
        105054a54b00714f8180a9c0d1c00101
        010101010101023a801871382d40582c
        4500dc0c1100001e000000ff00525946
        3337373448304536540a000000fc0044
        454c4c205332323138480a20000000fd
        00384c1e5311000a20202020202001f4
        02031ef14b90050403021101141f1213
        230907078301000065030c001000023a
        801871382d40582c4500dc0c1100001e
        011d8018711c1620582c2500dc0c1100
        009e011d007251d01e206e285500dc0c
        1100001e8c0ad08a20e02d10103e9600
        dc0c1100001800000000000000000000
        000000000000000000000000000000c1
    max bpc: 12 
        range: (8, 12)
    content type: No Data 
        supported: No Data, Graphics, Photo, Cinema, Game
    aspect ratio: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, 4:3, 16:9
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    audio: auto 
        supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
   1920x1080     60.00 +  50.00    59.94  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
   1680x1050_60.00  59.95*
```

> As you can see, my HDMI1 display does not support **scaling mode** . But I know that letterbox is possible for this monitor as
>   I have done so in Windows 10.

**Conclusion**

The main reason why I want it unstretched is because I am using a graphic tablet. Drawing on a stretched screen would mess up what one would try to draw. I might be overlooking something abut this is just taking too damn long to figure out. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @Nmath As I am running a 16:10 resolution on a 16:9 monitor, the display is stretched (imagine 800x600 stretched on 16:9 and using your wacom. Circles are not circles but oval shapes in output file). 

And thank you for correcting me, it's not a windows 10 setting but intel graphics setting (https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Zb8pQQ17SQQ/maxresdefault.jpg). I will see if I can find something to change intel graphics settings on ubuntu and will update the question.

Comment: @Nmath it is a personal preference (don't like widescreen). But now it's a question of why isn't this possible? Why can't I enable letterboxes? Imagine me having a low performance pc with a great monitor. If someone tried to run on 800x600 res, their experience with the stretched display would be terrible. Yes they could go buy another monitor but that would cost money that they don't have. (I know this is an extreme example but the question of why and how remains)